# Konjunktiv oder Präteritum

Tags: difference

Welchen Bedeutungsunterschied haben die folgenden Sätze:

> Die Ware hätte gestern geliefert werden sollen.
>
> Die Ware sollte gestern geliefert werden.

Answer (score 1):

*Geliefert werden* ist **Vorgangspassiv**. Zusammen mit dem Konjunktiv, einem Modalverb und Ersatzinfinitiv wird es schnell kompliziert:

> Die Ware hätte gestern **geliefert werden** sollen.
>
> Die Ware sollte gestern **geliefert werden**.

(Für Deutschlernende ist das vielleicht etwas entmutigend, aber: Der erste Satz ist kein akademisches Beispiel, Muttersprachler sprechen wirklich so.)

Einfacheres Beispiel ohne Passiv:

> Sie hätte gehen sollen. *(Konjunktiv II Perfekt mit Ersatzinfinitiv – Vergangenheit)*
>
> Sie sollte gehen. *(Konjunktiv II – Gegenwart / Indikativ Präteritum – Vergangenheit)*

Comment: Würden die beiden Sätze auch ausdrücken, dass die Ware nicht angekommen ist? Oder lieber so?: Die Ware wäre bereits angeliefert gewesen, wenn nicht der Fehler des Spediteurs

Comment: Es kommt auf die Betonung an: Betonst du *geliefert werden*, beschwerst du dich über die fehlende Lieferung, betonst du *gestern*, beschwerst du dich über die verspätete Lieferung.

Comment: *Die Ware wäre bereits angeliefert gewesen, wenn nicht der Fehler des Spediteurs …* – Das ist **Zustandspassiv** (sein+Partizip) und verschiebt daher das Geschehen zum Kunden. Das wirkt wie ein Schieben der Verantwortung zum Kunden, und weil beim Kunden ja eben gerade nichts passiert ist, wird der sich vielleicht nur wegen dieses Halbsatzes aufregen. Besser im Aktiv bleiben: *Wir hätten gerne geliefert, doch/aber der Spediteur hat einen Fehler gemacht.* Das klingt zwar immer noch wie eine billige Ausrede, aber zumindest ist der Kunde aus der Sache raus.

Comment: @Janka: Die Sätze könnten genauso gut vom Kunden gesprochen werden.

Comment: Die Sätze in meiner Antwort werden vom Kunden gesprochen. Der Satz *Die Ware wäre bereits angeliefert gewesen, wenn nicht der Fehler des Spediteurs…* aus dem Kommentar jedoch nicht.